# what type of glue do I use

Tags: wood, furniture

I am looking to re-glue the screw that connects a wood leg to a metal threaded bracket on a piece of furniture. The end that goes into the wood leg is stripped in the wood so the leg is loose, I tried liquid nails waited two days but they did not hold. Any ideas of what kind of glue to use?

Answer (score 2):

White or yellow PVA (Poly Vinyl Acetate) wood glue (elmers/titebond) and some new wood. Gluing in a few toothpicks is one method; drilling out the hole and gluing in a section of dowel is another.

Comment: +1 With special emphasis on the wood. The glue just holds the new wood in.  Toothpicks are great for screws with little strain, but for serious holding, drill, glue and insert a dowel.